# Bootstrap 3 Dropdown Menu Doesn't Drop Down

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

The dropdown menu isn't "dropping down." Here is my code:

```
<div class = "nav">
                <ul class = "pull-left">
                    <li><a class = "brand" href = "index.html">Go Back to Bryan's Corner</a></li>
                </ul>

                <ul class = "pull-right">
                    <li class = "quick-selection">Quick Selection Menu:</li>
                    <li><a href = "#">What Is The Bill of Rights?</a></li>

                    <li class = "dropdown">
                        <a href = "#" class = "dropdown-toggle" date-toggle = "dropdown">Amendments<strong class = "caret"></strong></a>

                        <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href = "1st Amendment"></a></li>
                            <li><a href = "2nd Amendment"></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                </ul>       
            </div>
```

When I say it doesn't drop down, I mean that when I hover over the amendments link, it doesn't give me a menu of more links to choose from.

I have Java Script enabled:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you import `bootstrap.js`?

Comment: Yes, I have Java Script.

Comment: Please provide a live example, preferably on jsfiddle. Also, it's Javascript, not "Java script", they are two completely different things

Comment: You should use css for this rather than js i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only find some syntax spelling errors (i.e. `date` instead of `data`)... Seems to have done the trick:

## HTML:

```
<div class = "nav">
    <ul class = "pull-left">
        <li><a class = "brand" href = "index.html">Go Back to Bryan's Corner</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class = "pull-right">
        <li class = "quick-selection">Quick Selection Menu:</li>
        <li><a href = "#">What Is The Bill of Rights?</a></li>
        <li class = "dropdown"><a href = "#" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">Amendments<strong class = "caret"></strong></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href = "1st Amendment">1st Amendment</a></li>
                <li><a href = "2nd Amendment">2nd Amendment</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>       
</div>
```

## Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/RaAQ5/

P.S.: You don't actually need `role`, but it's conventional in bootstrap ^_^.